# Import datadump in schema mode

Tags: oracle, schema, migration, oracle-11g, impdp

why am I encountering this error when executing impdp command?

My command looks like this:

```
impdp directory=dp_dir dumpfile=testdb.dmp logfile=testdb.log
```

Error message:

```
ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39070: Unable to open the log file.
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem has been fixed. I just executed

```
chmod -R 777 <my_data_pump_folder>
```

Seems that I don't have the privilege to write in `<my_data_pump_folder>`

Comment: As far as the OS is concerned, the one asking to do I/O in that directory is the OS user that started the oracle db.  That would normally be "oracle".  So instead of the overly-permissive '777', the permissions really don't need to be any more than 700 or 770, with the directory owned by oracle;oinstall or oracle:dba

Answer (score 2):

One way to find the cause of ORA errors is to use `oerr` tool by Oracle. In the error stack the top most is the application error which is followed by other secondary errors.

For example, the `ORA-39002` and `ORA-39070` are Datapump errors. Lets see what the `oerr` tool says for `ORA-39070`.

> [oracle@localhost ~]$ oerr ORA 39070
>   39070, 00000, "Unable to open the log file."
>   **Cause:**  Errors were detecting while opening the log file.  Subsequent
>            messages will detail the problems.
>   **Action:** Fix the problems outlined in the secondary messages.

The action is to fix the problem outlined by the secondary error message that is `ORA-29283`.

> [oracle@localhost ~]$ oerr ORA 29283
>   29283, 00000, "invalid file operation"
>   **Cause:**  An attempt was made to read from a file or directory that does
>            not exist, or file or directory access was denied by the 
>            operating system.
>   **Action:** Verify file and directory access privileges on the file system,
>             and if reading, verify that the file exists.

And that's it.